# Как открывать с поддомена домена, привязанного к одному серверу, директорию на другом сервере

Tags: dns, apache2

Итак есть 2 сервера и 2 домена. Назовем их сервер A и B и домен A и B соответственно.
Был создан поддомен домена А и в него были прописаны DNS сервера B.

Требуется чтобы при открытии этого поддомена открывалась определенная директория на сервере B.

Как мне реализовать поставленную задачу? Спасибо!

P.S.На сервере B стоит apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, необходимо чтобы файлы в директории В были с правами на "выполнение", но имейте ввиду, это крайне опасно, т.к. любой может выполнить их на Ваш сервере, если вы не ограничите доступ по IP. А во-вторых, для подобных задач есть запросы POST и GET, нужно решать с помощью них.